# Bot sends reaction message without a reaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bots, discord.js, message

So my bot now instantly sends the "A" reaction message after the first message but without a reaction from the user. It shouldnt do that. Why? I have no errors.

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    try {
        member.send(`Hello ${member}, welcome to the PotatoHost Server! 
I want to help you and so my question is: Do you want to buy a server or do you need more informations first? \n
A: I want to buy a server
B: I need more informations first \n
Please react to this message with A or B.`)

        .then(function (message) {
            message.react("")
            message.react("")

            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['', 'B'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
            };

            message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 3600000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(collected => {
                    const reaction = collected.first();

                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                        message.channel.send('Ok, so you want to buy a server. Let me recommend you to visit <#699374469977735208>.');
                    }
                    else {
                        message.channel.send('Ok, so you need more informations first. Let me recommend you to visit <#699374469977735208>.');
                    }    
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                    message.channel.send('You reacted with neither A or B.');
                })
        });
    }catch (err) {
         console.log(err)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that you are overwriting the original `message` object. In your filter, you want to make sure it is the member's id so no one else can claim it,

```
&& user.id === message.author.id
```

However, `message` in this case is referring to the message your bot is sending —`.then(function (message) {`. Therefore, your code reads the filter as the ID has to match your bot, and since your bot reacts with A, it spits out the A reaction message.

To fix this, change the filter stated before to

```
&& user.id === member.id
```

**EDIT**

Second problem: B. Your filter is only finding  or B, you need to change B to the emoji version in `return ['', 'B']`.

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much, it worked you were right, so now when i react with A it sends message A but when I react with B it doesnt send any message (No error). Do you know why?

Comment: @NicoHd105 Edited my answer to include that; hope it helps :)

Comment: Again you were right. Thanks a 100 times and all the best to you.

Comment: No problem! To help others, please mark this question as correct by hitting the checkmark. Have a good day!